# Edas submission Camera ready problem

Tags: margins, ieeetran, conversion, ieeeconf

I'm about to submit my PDF CR version for IEEEconf but I have got the following error

```
PNG conversion problem (1)
    Array
(
    [0] => gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pbmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=1" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=1" "-r200x200" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmq0BIGA" "--" "/tmp/gmft3NTx" "-c" "quit" (child process quit due to signal 11).
    [1] => gm convert: Unexpected end-of-file (/tmp/gmq0BIGA).
)
```

Also

```
Upload failed: Invalid PDF detected during margin check: gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pbmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=1" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=1" "-r200x200" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmq0BIGA" "--" "/tmp/gmft3NTx" "-c" "quit" (child process quit due to signal 11).
gm convert: Unexpected end-of-file (/tmp/gmq0BIGA).
```

The PDF version is certified and checked by PDF-eXpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I obviously had problems with embedded fonts in the figures. I opened the figures using Inkscape and its generated PDF version. Then, I had the final version checked using PDFeXpress, then successfully uploaded to edas.